# How can i link an html page to an button in ionic using angular?

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an ionic 1 application and I want to open a page when I click on a button I have tried to do so using online tutorials but none seems to help me.I know how to do it in HTML but I'm new to angular.

Index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <div class="bar bar-header">
  <h1 class="title">Header</h1>
</div>
<div class="bar bar-subheader">
  <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
  <div class="button-bar bar-balanced">
  <a class="button">First page </a>
  <a class="button">Second page </a>
  <a class="button">Third page</a>
</div>
</div>
      <ion-content>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

App.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);


      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: I don't see any routing mechanism in your app, also no actions bound to your buttons. Do some tutorials first

Comment: i have done tutorials on angular they all show method using ngrouting which when i implement does nothing in ionic that is why i have presented a blank code so that someone can show me how do i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic uses angular's ui routing by default, so you can do something like this:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("first", {
            url: "/first",
            template: "<div>This is first page</div>"
        });
    // other states

    // default
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/first");
});
```

Then in your button:

```
<a class="button"
   ui-sref="first">First page </a>
```

And somewhere to let Ionic know where to load your views:

```
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: Devqon's dont i need a onclick() when i click the button ?

Comment: No that's what the `ui-sref` is for. You can also do it in a `ng-click`, but you should only do that if you apply more logic than just routing

Answer (score 0):

With ui-sref, it changes the state of the html page since angular is a single page application, no on-click is required for this, whatever you name the state of your page is what you call within the ui-sref. For instance

.state('thispage', {

url: 'thispage',

templateUrl: '/thispage.html',

// controller: 'thispageCtrl'

}

All this is within the state Provider..